# I am trying to have a wall follow robot but there are errors on the names not being declared in my scope I need help

Tags: c++, robotics

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libplayerc++/playerc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
using namespace PlayerCc;  
PlayerClient    robot("localhost");  
BumperProxy      bp(&robot,0);  
Position2dProxy pp(&robot,0);
pp.SetMotorEnable(true);


for(;;)
    double turnrate, speed;
double error;
bool wall;

motor_a_speed(0);
motor_c_speed(0);

while(1) {

    front_bumper = SENSOR_2;
    left_bumper = SENSOR_3;

    if (front_bumper > 2) {

        if (left_bumper < 3) {

            motor_a_speed(5);

            motor_c_speed(drive_speed);
            motor_a_dir(fwd);
            motor_c_dir(fwd);

        }

        else {

            motor_a_speed(drive_speed);

            motor_c_speed(5);
            motor_a_dir(rev);
            motor_c_dir(rev);

        }

    }

    else {

        motor_a_speed(drive_speed);

        motor_c_speed(drive_speed);
        motor_a_dir(brake);
        motor_c_dir(brake);
        mrest(100);

        cputs("bump");

        motor_a_dir(fwd);
        motor_c_dir(rev);
        msleep(450);


        cputs("right");

        motor_a_speed(10);
        motor_a_dir(fwd);
        motor_c_dir(fwd);
        mrest(1300);

    }

    pp.SetSpeed(speed, turnrate);
}
```

Comment: @Sam Please provide more specific information, such as the errors you're receiving. Just posting code is generally frowned upon, and may not be received well by the community.

Comment: Not to mention that the code formatting is bad.  In particular, your `motor_a_speed` calls seem to be always left-justified rather than indented with the other code in the block, and your braces are haphazard.

Answer (score 5):

Given the bad indentation, the only thing that jumps out at me is

```
for(;;;)
double turnrate, speed;
```

Since the `for` isn't followed by a block in braces, its body is the next statement.  It isn't a construct I've seen often, but I believe what happens is that the `for` statement contains a definition of `turnrate` and `speed`, which are local to the `for` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I've reformatted the sourcecode to a more readable version. Could someone with editing clearance replace the OP's source with this?

Using identation, the for loop without braces is clearly visvible as a cause of trouble. A short test (i didn't no how this would work) showed that a for(;;) - loop will loop forever, so the OP's Program will never do anything useful.
It should probably be removed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libplayerc++/playerc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    using namespace PlayerCc;  
    PlayerClient    robot("localhost");  
    BumperProxy      bp(&robot,0);  
    Position2dProxy pp(&robot,0);
    pp.SetMotorEnable(true);


    for(;;)
        double turnrate, speed;
    double error;
    bool wall;

    motor_a_speed(0);
    motor_c_speed(0);

    while(1) {

        front_bumper = SENSOR_2;
        left_bumper = SENSOR_3;

        if (front_bumper > 2) {

            if (left_bumper < 3) {

                motor_a_speed(5);

                motor_c_speed(drive_speed);
                motor_a_dir(fwd);
                motor_c_dir(fwd);

            }

            else {

                motor_a_speed(drive_speed);

                motor_c_speed(5);
                motor_a_dir(rev);
                motor_c_dir(rev);

            }

        }

        else {

            motor_a_speed(drive_speed);

            motor_c_speed(drive_speed);
            motor_a_dir(brake);
            motor_c_dir(brake);
            mrest(100);

            cputs("bump");

            motor_a_dir(fwd);
            motor_c_dir(rev);
            msleep(450);


            cputs("right");

            motor_a_speed(10);
            motor_a_dir(fwd);
            motor_c_dir(fwd);
            mrest(1300);

        }

        pp.SetSpeed(speed, turnrate);
    }
}
```